# Como fazer o docker-compose exportar a porta do Postgres para o host?

Tags: django, docker

Estou utilizando django e docker-compose em um projeto. A principio o settings do projeto esta como default o SQLite, mas mudei para PostgreSQL. Preciso permitir utilizar o Postgres mesmo rondando via virtualven, sendo possivel das duas maneiras

- rodar o projeto via docker -> docker-copmose up --build;
- Utilizando o postgres no docker e o código na virtualenv -> docker-compose up database   e   python runserver;

Como faço o docker-compose exportar a porta do Postgres para o host?

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    api:
        image: projeto
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        links:
            - "database:database"
    database:
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        environment:
            POSTGRES_NAME: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            POSTGRES_HOST: 127.0.0.1
            POSTGRES_PORT: 5432

        volumes:
            - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
    database:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . /var/www

RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Create non-privileged user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/sh django
USER django

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro... evite usar `links` no docker-compose.yml. É uma feature depreciada do Docker e logo não estará mais disponível. Para acessar outro container do mesmo compose, coloque o campo `container_name` em cada um e todos eles podem se encontrar pelo nome.

Para expor a porta do PostgreSQL, basta usar o `ports`, como você já tem no caso do `app`. Coloque uma lista de portas no `database`.

```yaml
    database:
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
```